# How to assign an index of the groupby categories to every value in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, data-preprocessing

I have dataframe (df):
[image]

Here we have user_id, order_completed_at (date of order), cart (product id), and reordered (was it ordered previously?) columns. I want to add one more column to the df that will contain the number of order made by particular user. For example, user #2 made his first order at 2015-03-22 09:25:46, and this is his first order, so we put 1 to every row in a new column next to 'cart' item. Next time when there is user_id = 2 makes his order (another date but again user_id = 2), all 'cart' items will be indexed by 2, because it is his second order from our company. And I have to do it for all the users and their orders. Example (reordered column was dropped, it is not important right here):

[image]

I tried some groupby combinations, it didn`t bring right result, but maybe give you some ideas:

[image]

Here it looks like task is done, but you can notice that user_id = 3 and cart = 399 is indexed as 2 and 3 (and I have to get 1, because this is simply the first order is made by the third user). I got just appearance of every cart items in dataframe in this kernel.

Hope you will have some ideas, guys

Comment: It would be better if you could provide a sample data frame for people to work with.